# Lookup to match from one dataset to another

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I need help multiplying the values from data set 2 to data set 1.

Data#1:

| policy# | Risk# | Premium |
| --- | --- | --- |
| KOK1 | 002 | 150 |
| KOK2 | 003 | 130 |

Data#2:

| Source | policy# | Risk# | Item1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ageofbuild | KOK1 | 002 | 3 |
| yearofbuild | KOK1 | 002 | 5 |
| Discount1 | KOK1 | 002 | 10% |
| Discount2 | KOK1 | 002 | 5% |
| ageofbuild | KOK2 | 003 | 4 |
| yearofbuild | KOK2 | 003 | 6 |
| Discount1 | KOK2 | 003 | 15% |
| Discount2 | KOK2 | 003 | 5% |

How to set up a formula to match the policy# and risk# from data#1 to data#2 and multiply the "premium" in data#1 with discount1 and discount2 from data#2 if they match the policy# and risk#?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do this. The first way is a simple merge where you merge the dataset by policy and risk #, then perform your calculations. For example:

```
data want;
    merge data2(in=d2)
          data1(in=d1);
    by policy risk_nbr;

    /* If policy and risk_nbr match from data2 and data1, then calculate
       a premium */
    if(d2 AND d1 AND find(source, 'Discount') ) then value = Premium*Item1;
   
run;
```

This is similar to a full join on `policy, risk_nbr` in SQL, but only multiplying if the two key values match. Note that both datasets must be sorted by `policy` and `risk_nbr` for this to work.

The second way is through a hash table lookup, which is one of my favorite ways of doing these small lookup tables. They're *really* fast.

Think of a hash table as an independent table that floats out in memory. We're going to talk to it using special methods that look up a value in the hash table by a key in our dataset and pull that value down so we can use it. Here's what that looks like.

```
data want;

    /* Only load the hash table once */
    if(_N_ = 1) then do;
        dcl hash h(dataset: 'data2');      *Add a dataset to a hash table called 'h';
            h.defineKey('policy', 'risk'); *Define our lookup key;
            h.defineData('premium');       *The value we want to pull;
        h.defineDone();                    *Load the dataset into `h`;
      
        /* Initialize the numeric variable 'premium' with a missing value 
           since it does not exist yet. This prevents data step warnings. */
        call missing(premium); 
    end;
    
    /* Look up the value of policy and risk in the set dataset and compare it 
       with the hash table's value of policy and risk.
       If there is a match, rc = 0
    */
    rc = h.Find();

    if(rc = 0 AND find(source, 'Discount') ) then value = Premium*Item1;

    drop rc;
run;
```

Hash tables are extremely powerful and very fast, especially if you are joining a small table with a large table. You don't need to do any pre-sorting, either.

If you want to learn more about hash tables, check out the paper [I cut my processing time by 90% using hash tables - you can too!](https://www.lexjansen.com/nesug/nesug07/bb/bb16.pdf)

Comment: Hi there, thank you so much for the comment. I tried using the hash table but im running into an error: "Undeclared key symbol POLICY for has object at line n column m" How would I fix that?

Comment: The variable `policy` must be in both datasets. You may need to modify the hash table code to use the variable names of your datasets. If the policy number's variable name is different in both datasets, post here and I can show you how to fix it.

Comment: Policy is in both data sets. Now I am getting a syntax error in the 3rd last line (if(rc = 0 AND find(source), 'Discount') then value = Premium*Item1;). I am not sure how to get around that

Comment: I also tried using the first way too but it says work.dataset2 does not exist. Do you know why it says that?

Comment: It means your datasets you're trying to merge are not in the `work` library. You need to point to where the datasets are stored. I made a typo in the syntax and have corrected it.

Comment: Yea you're right it is not stored in the work library but it is part of the same chain of the code. So, how would point dataset2? Thank you for all the help btw, I am new to this so I might be asking basic questions.

Comment: Change wherever you see `data1` and `data2`  to wherever your datasets are stored (e.g. if data1 is called `dataset1` in the `lib` library, change it to `lib.dataset1`)

Comment: I changed it to lib.dataset2 and lib.dataset1 but now there's another error: Libref LIB is not assigned.

Comment: It needs to literally be the library and dataset name where your data is stored. I only can give you a generic example. I do not know where your data is stored or what it is called, so I cannot provide you with the exact library or dataset names. I recommend reading this article to get started: https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/lepg/9.4/p1r10h01312au5n10blzbelljk7r.htm

Comment: Yes I figured that out but now there is another error saying "BY variables are not properly sorted on data set lib.dataset2"

Comment: You will need to sort both of your datasets by `policy risk_nbr` in that order to do the first answer by using `proc sort`. The benefit of the hash table approach is that you do not need to do this.