# SAS COLUMN MERGING WITH UNEQUAL ROWS -

Tags: sas

I need to create a 3rd table which will look like the following:

Data1:

| policy | Risk | Premium |
| --- | --- | --- |
| KOK1 | 002 | 150 |
| KOK2 | 003 | 130 |

Data2:

| Source | policy | Risk | Item1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ageofbuild | KOK1 | 002 | 3 |
| yearofbuild | KOK1 | 002 | 5 |
| Discount | KOK1 | 002 | 10% |
| Discount | KOK1 | 002 | 5% |
| ageofbuild | KOK2 | 003 | 4 |
| yearofbuild | KOK2 | 003 | 6 |
| Discount | KOK2 | 003 | 15% |
| Discount | KOK2 | 003 | 7% |
| Discount | KOK2 | 003 | 3% |

Use dataset1 and dataset2 to create dataset 3?

Data3: (an extension of dataset1 with a discount column)

| policy | Risk | Premium | Discount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| KOK1 | 002 | 150 | 10%*5% |
| KOK2 | 003 | 130 | 15%*7%*3% |

How do I set up a formula where policy and risk in data1 matches with policy and risk in dataset2 and grabs the discounts (multiplies them) and then creates a new table called data3 which is an extension of dataset1 with an additional column at the end called discount. Can someone please set up a code for me to achieve that?

I tried merging and using Hash tables but it did not work. I don't have much knowledge on SAS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lookup to match from one dataset to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74434395/lookup-to-match-from-one-dataset-to-another)

Comment: No unfortunately, I tried using that approach but didn't work. Now, I think it might be easier to use a different approach and create a 3rd table rather with an extra column

Comment: Please don't use tags for a language unless you are looking for help with that language. I'm removing the Javascript, Python, SQL, and R tags since they don't have anything to do with mergning data in SAS.

Answer (score 0):

First thing is to convert your listings into actual datasets so we can see what TYPE of variables you have.  So lets assume you meant you had data like this:

```
data policy ;
  input policy $ Risk $ Premium ;
cards;
KOK1 002 150
KOK2 003 130
;

data rules ;
  input Source :$20. policy $ Risk $ Item1 :8.2;
cards;
ageofbuild KOK1 002 3
yearofbuild KOK1 002 5
Discount KOK1 002 10
Discount KOK1 002 5
ageofbuild KOK2 003 4
yearofbuild KOK2 003 6
Discount KOK2 003 15
Discount KOK2 003 7
Discount KOK2 003 3
;
```

Now we just need to merge the two and concatenate the ITEM1 values for the observations where source is DISCOUNT.  To make it LOOK like your output I made the new DISCOUNT variable a character string.

```
proc sort data=rules ;
  by policy risk;
run;

proc sort data=policy;
  by policy risk;
run;

data want;
  merge policy (in=in1) rules (in=in2 where=(source='Discount'));
  by policy risk;
  length discount $30 ;
  retain discount;
  if in1 ;
  if first.risk then discount=' ';
  if in2 then discount=catx('*',discount,put(item1,percent5.));
  if last.risk;
  keep policy risk premium discount;
run;
```

Result

```
Obs    policy    Risk    Premium    discount

 1      KOK1     002       150      10%*5%
 2      KOK2     003       130      15%*7%*3%
```

You do not explain what multiplying discounts mean ( I doubt that combining a 5% discount with a 3% discount means you want 0.015% discount that the multiplication symbol in your listing implies).  Do you want to add them? So 5% + 3% yields 8%?  Compound them in some other way?

Comment: What does the "percent.5" represent in this line "if in2 then discount=catx('*',discount,put(item1,percent.));" Also, if I actually want to see the value ex. 0.10*0.05 = 0.005 instead of 10%*5%, what do I need to do?

Comment: PERCENT5. is a FORMAT. Formats are instructions for how to convert values into text.  If you wanted a numeric variable DISCOUNT then define it as numeric (length of 8 instead of $30) and initialize it to a number and assign it numeric values.  It is probably easiest to initialize it to 1 and then multiply the value new values.  `discount=discount*item1;` .     But perhaps you want a different value than 1 when no discounts are found?

Comment: If no discounts are found then I want to keep it blank. Also, I just tired modifying the code and my want table, discount column has a "." instead of 0.005. Do you know where I messed up? Here is the code below:

Comment: proc sort data=rules ;
  by policy risk;
run;

proc sort data=policy;
  by policy risk;
run;

data want;
  merge policy (in=in1) rules (in=in2 where=(source='Discount'));
  by policy risk;
  length discount $30 ;
  retain discount;
  if in1 ;
  if first.risk then discount=' ';
  if in2 then discount=discount*Item1
  if last.risk;
  keep policy risk premium discount;
run;

Comment: Not quite.  You are still defining DISCOUNT as a character string.  `length discount $30;` and initializing it to a blank string. `if .... discount=' ';`.  You also are missing the semicolon to end the second if/then statement.

Comment: Oh sorry I made a typo there, it should be length discount 8;

Comment: Note that 10%*5% is .005000 or 0.5%.  Is that what you really want?  I think if you want to compound you might want to do `discount=discount*(1-item1);` and then at the end convert `discount=1-discount;`.  Then 10%*5% will become 14.5%.  But talk to a finance expert, not a programmer.

Comment: That should be fine because if its 5% then its actually a factor of 0.95. I should've written that instead but even after running the code I am getting a period in the discount column. do you know why?

Comment: Did you initialize it to 1? Or are you still trying to initialize it to a blank character string when you start a new group?  If you multiply with numbers where one of them is missing the result is missing.